# how register next step handler in pyrogram?

Tags: python, handler, pyrogram

I can't find similar method like in `telebot`, it should be one Time handler to ask user something and after user send something we can work with this update object

I tried this code from stackoverflow

```
bot = Client("bot")


@bot.on_message(filters.command('start'))
def start(bot, msg):
    x=input
    bot.send_message(msg.chat.id,text=x)
    
bot.run()
```

.

```
>>>AttributeError: 'Chat' object has no attribute 'ask'
```

maybe someone know how implement this in program,

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.